# Increase the number of simultaneous Remote Desktop (TS) connections

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

how do I increase the number of simultaneous remote desktop connections on my server on Google Compute Engine? do I need to acquire the access CAL with the GC?

Answer (score 3):

Steps are as follows to increase the number of simultaneous connections:

1.Open the ‘Server Manager’ window on the Instance

2.On the top right of click on ‘Manage’ and then on the ‘Add Roles and Features’ option

3.Click ‘next’ on the ‘Before you begin’ welcome message

4.Select the ‘Role-based or feature-based installation’ setting and click ‘Next’

5.Select the ‘Select a server from the server pool’ option and then click ‘Next’

6.From the list, put a checkbox on the ‘Remote Desktop Services’ option and and click ‘Next’

7.On the ‘Role Services’ section, select the ‘Remote desktop session host’ option and when prompted click on the ‘Add features’ button on the pop-up window and finally ‘Next’

8.Restart the Instance from Windows upon the installation completion

9.After the instance restarts, press the Windows ‘Start’ button and search for ‘Run’

10.On the ‘Run’ window type ‘gpedit.msc’ and open it

11.Once the ‘Local Group Policy Editor’ opens, go to ‘Computer Configuration’ > ‘Administrative Templates’ > ‘Windows Components’ > ‘Remote Desktop Services’ > ‘Remote Desktop Session Host’ > ‘Connections’

12.Inside set the ‘Restrict Remote Desktop Services user to a single Remote Desktop Services session’ policy to the ‘Disabled’ setting

13.Now double click on the ‘Limit number of connections’ and set it to ‘Enabled’. On this same window set the ‘RD Maximum Connections allowed’ to ‘999999’ and apply settings

14.Restart the Instance a final time from Windows